# What is the PURPOSE of deserializing json in C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C# MVC and json I really want to know what the *purpose* is to deserializing json in C# mvc using JSON.NET.

What can I do with the data afterward?

Can I make an HTML table from it in *just* MVC? Can I use the data to create a database?

This is me doing research just so I can have a better understanding of the environment I will be working with going forward. Any help in understanding it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you get to the data if you _didn't_ deserialize it?  Deserialization lets you work with strongly-types classes and collections.

Comment: _"Can I make an HTML table from it in just MVC? Can I use the data to create a database?"_ - wow, you _really_ don't understand it do you? JSON is just a way of transferring data from one system to another in a common way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is just a way for applications and services to communicate. Think of it like the old-fashioned string with two cans connected to each other.

Pretend you are living in a high rise apartment in New York City. And you look out your window and across the street, you have a friend also living in a high rise apartment. You two whip out your cans connected with a string and start talking.

In this analogy, you are "Application A" and your friend is "Application B". The string and cans would be the network and the sound modulation thats modulating the string between the 2 cans and the English Language would be Json.

When you talk into your can, your voice and what you're saying is being "serialized" as its being modulated over the string and converted into frequencies and modulation. Your friend, or "Application B" receives those modulations on his can and his ear is "deserializing" those frequencies and modulations and converting them back into speech and English that he can understand.

Your data is going through the same process. Instead of frequencies and amplitudes, its Json. You need to be able to deserialize the data so you can work with it. Imagine if your friend simply wrote down frequencies and amplitudes. Imagine trying to convert that into a speech pattern!

Comment: Nice analogy.  Perhaps to make things fit better with the OP's question "Application A" and "Application B" could be renamed to "server" and "client", or "web server" and "browser".

Comment: Thank you for that. I understand it a lot better now.

Answer (score 4):

The exchange of data between a client and a server can be done in many ways. In all cases the data that are exchanged should have some format. In some cases data could be in xml format. In other cases could be in json format and so on and so forth.

The json format is a very convenient way for exchanging data between a client and a server because it is very easy for it to be consumed by the client using plain JavaScript.

Furthermore, it is very easy to format the data you want to send from the server to the client in json. But what are you going to do, when the client sends a json to the server? There comes the opposite of the serialization, which is the deserialization. You deserialize the json string you get, you do whatever you want and then you respond properly to the client.

Comment: What do you mean by "for the client to be consumed"?

Comment: I mean that the client requests a list of products that the client wants to show them in a table. The response of the server would be consumed by the client, in order to build this table. Saying consume, you could imagine as (for instance) a for loop through the items of an array returned from the  server.